# Что лучше call или start?

Tags: cmd

Что лучше использовать call или start?
Что выгоднее, разумнее, оптимальнее использовать на платформе Windows из этих двух команд командного процессора данной ОС?
Допустим для вызова\старта ПО, которое в виде приложения exe?

Comment: Выгоднее, разумнее и оптимальние с каких позиций?

Comment: согласно документации - call запускает другой батник в этом же процессе. А start запускает исполняемый файл (в том числе и батник) в отдельном процессе.

Comment: Автор, откуда у вас вообще взялась метка `dos`?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации - `call` запускает другой батник в этом же процессе. А `start` запускает исполняемый файл (в том числе и батник) в отдельном процессе.

– KoVadim